# Is there eot font editor?

Tags: fonts

Is there an editor for eot fonts? Known editors like font forge and font creator and font lab doesn't support eot font type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, but you can do an .eot->.ttf and edit from there. There have been many failed attempts to reverse engineer .eot, such as [Reverse Engineering the Embedded OpenType Decompression](http://securitylabs.websense.com/content/Blogs/3114.aspx). However, this one works and I've used it to save an .eot to a .ttf: [Rhymes with Amharic #4](http://www.siao2.com/2007/04/14/2137215.aspx). During the save process, you can edit a number of meta-properties as well.

Comment: Hi Todd, came across this now, could you please enlighten me toward using the **Rhymes with Amharic #4** Many thanks in advance

Comment: [onlinefontconverter.com](https://onlinefontconverter.com) can easily convert eot to ttf or any other format without installing any extra programs